# Problemas con setImageResource en Android Studio

Tags: java

Soy novato en esto de Android Studio y, después de ver muchos ejemplos y demás, he decidido hacer una aplicación donde hay una imagen y un texto.
Tengo un ActivityMain donde, mediante una consulta SQlite, obtengo de dicha base de datos, un campo nombrefruta y otro fotofruta.
En la carpeta drawable, tengo las fotos de las frutas, por ejemplo: manzana.jpg,pera.jpg,melon.jpg...etc.
Ahora, quiero cargar ese texto y esa imagen que me ha devuelto la consulta en un RecyclerView, mediante un AdaptadorFrutas.AdaptadorFrutasHolder.

En el código , en el procedimiento onBindViewHolder tengo lo siguiente:
holder.texto.setText(textodevueltoporlaconsulta);
Este código no me da ningún problema. El problema viene con a la hora de "cargar" la imágen en el ImageView.
He puesto el siguiente código:

```
String uri ="drawable/"+nombreimagendevueltoporlaconsulta;
int resid = getResources().getIdentifier(uri,"drawable",getPackageName());
holder.imagen.setImageResource(resid);
```

Aquí es donde tengo el problema, porque se supone que `setImageResource` tendría que pasarle un valor entero, que hago con la variable `resid`, pero siempre me da 0.
He probado hacer muchas combinaciones  y NINGUNA ME FUNCIONA.
Ya no se que hacer... ¿alguna ayuda, por favor?.
¡¡ gracias !!

```
  int resid = getResources()
```

Comment: nombreimagendevueltoporlaconsulta  debe contener el nombre de la imagen sin la extensión, debes usar setImageDrawable() ya que obtendrás un Drawable en base al id de la imagen, hay varios cambios que realizar, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Tu adaptador deberia tener este modelo

public class adpDirectorio extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adpDirectorio.ViewHolderAdaptador> {

```
ArrayList<String> Lista;
private View.OnClickListener listener;

public adpDirectorio(ArrayList<String>list){

    Lista=list;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolderAdaptador onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View vista= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.directorioadp,null,false);
    
    return new adpDirectorio.ViewHolderAdaptador(vista);
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderAdaptador holder, int position) {

    if(("(textoRecibido)").contains("melon")){
        holder.texto.setText("TextoRecibidoConsulta");
        holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.melon);
    }    

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Lista.size();
}

public class ViewHolderAdaptador extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView ruta;
    ImageView img;
    public ViewHolderAdaptador(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ruta=itemView.findViewById(R.id.TvRutas);
        img=itemView.findViewById(R.id.Icon);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Te sugerimos por favor revisar [answer], evita realizar varias respuestas en la misma publicación., ya que tus publicaciones serían eliminadas.

Comment: Muchas gracias David. Es un código que tengo que mirar para ver como lo puedo "aplicar" a mi código. Pero creo que más o menos está todo igual. Lo que pasa es que al poner el if del contains...sería enorme puesto que quiero cargar alrededor de 100 frutas. Pero lo voy a mirar y mañana, ya te cuento. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Asegura que `nombreimagendevueltoporlaconsulta` en verdad contiene un nombre de imagen que se encuentra en Drawable, este nombre de imagen no debe contener la extensión.

El método del [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) que debes usar es [setImageDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) ya que lo que obtendrás es un Drawable de la imagen.

```
String uri ="@drawable/"+nombreimagendevueltoporlaconsulta.replace(".jpg","");
//int resid = getResources().getIdentifier(uri,"drawable",getPackageName());
int resid = getResources().getIdentifier(uri,null,getPackageName()); //*Se define null, ya que en la URI se definió que se encuentra en drawable/

//* Obtiene imagen con base al id del recurso.
Drawable drawableRes = getResources().getDrawable(resid);

//* Carga Drawable en ImageView usando setImageDrawable()
//holder.imagen.setImageResource(resid);
holder.imagen.setImageDrawable(drawableRes);
```

Comment: Hola , Jorgesys. Gracias por responderme, pero no me funciona.

Comment: Agrega un replace para que elimine la extensión, no debe llevar la extensión del archivo :     String uri ="@drawable/"+nombreimagendevueltoporlaconsulta.replace(".jpg","");   e imprime  el valor de "url" solo asegura que el nombre del archivo exista en verdad. @jgmgm

Comment: Hola Jorgesys. La extensión, al final se la he puesto yo " a mano " para evitar problemas. Me queda algo tal que uri = "@drawable/manzana".
En la carpeta drawable tengo una imagen guardada como manzana.jpg

Comment: Ok, lo que dices es correcto, muy importante revisar el LogCat, se despliega algún error?

Comment: Me indica:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual methos ' void android.widget.Imageview.SetImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object.
Ademas en 
Drawable drawableRes = getResources().getDrawable(imageresource), la palabra (getDrawable, aparece con una línea sobre dicha palabra, como si estuviera deprecated).

Comment: Aquí el problema ahora es que holder.imagen. tiene valor null, Agrega todo tu adapter por favor,

Answer (score -1):

si tienes tus imagenes en la carpeta drawble solo tienes que hacer lo siguiente

```
holder.imagen.setImageResource(R.drawble.melon);
```

donde melon es el nombre con el que guardaste tu imagen

Comment: Hola, David. Muchas gracias por responderme.
Pero tengo la siguiente duda. ¿Que tengo que crear un string que sea, R.drawable.[nombrevariablequeobtengodelaconsulta]?. Porque de la consulta a la tabla de la base de datos he obtendio, por ejemplo, melon.jpg.
¿Entonces que creo la variable R.drawable.melon.jpg?. No se si me explico.

Comment: Como te comento, si ya tienes guardadas tus imagenes en la carpeta drawble no necesitas variables, puedes acceder a ellas como si ligaras un elemento cualquiera a una variable con findView(R.id.[Nombre de elemento], solo que en lugar de buscar id tu buscas un elemento drawble, por lo cual no requieres ninguna variable, espero darme a entender
¿ya probaste el codigo?

Comment: Hola David, no te sigo. Perdóname mi torpeza. He probado tu código, pero es que no se que poner detrás del drawable. Porque, si en la consulta a la base de datos obtengo que el nombre de la foto es melon.jpg.. ¿Cómo pongo eso en el setImageResource?.
En cuanto a esto---"puedes acceder a ellas como si ligaras un elemento cualquiera a una variable con findView(R.id.[Nombre de elemento], solo que en lugar de buscar id tu buscas un elemento drawble, por lo cual no requieres ninguna variable".. perdóname nuevamente mi torpeza, pero no te sigo. Soy novato en esto y estoy casi empezando. Muchas grac

Comment: David, acabo de probar lo siguiente:
int[] foto = {R.drawable.melon};
holder.imagen.setImageResource(foto[0]);
Por probar otra opción y nada, me sigue dando error.
El caso es que la foto aparace en el drawable como melon.jpg, pero solo me acepta como válido {R.drawable.melon}, y NO {R.drawable.melon.jpg}.
La verdad es que me estoy volviendo loco...

Comment: a ok, no te preocupes no es necesario poner la extencion del archivo, {R.drawable.melon} esta forma es correcta

Comment: public AdaptadorFrutas.AdaptadorFrutasHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new AdaptadorFrutasHolder(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.celda,parent,false)); }
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdaptadorFrutas.AdaptadorFrutasHolder holder, int position) {
            String imagen = listaFrutas.get(position).getImagenFrutas();
            String nombre = listaFrutas.get(position).getNombreFrutas();
            holder.imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.melon);

Comment: Me ha desaparecido las ultimas 5 respuestas tuyas. No se que ha pasado con stackoverflow.

Comment: Ese es todo tu codigo? noto que faltan partes

Si pudieras editar la pregunta y pegar el codigo completo ahí  se podra ver mejor

Comment: Es que no puedo poner todo el código aqui, me dice que excedo el número de caracteres...si pudiera enviártelo de otra forma...

Comment: edita la pregunta, ahi si te permite pegar todo el codigo